# map a float value to key which is a pair

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a map and map a float value to key which is of type pair. I am not able display the map using the display function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
typedef pair<int, int> Key; //pair

void display (map <Key,float> &m) // to print maps
{
    cout << "\tTotal size: " << m.size() << endl; 
    map <Key,float>::iterator it;
    for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
       cout << setw(10) << it->first << setw(5) << it->second << endl;

    cout << endl; 
}

int main() {

map< Key , float> mapa; //create map

Key p1 (1, 45); //key values
Key p2 (2, 20);

mapa[p1]= 25.11; //map float to keys
mapa[p2]= 11.23;

display(mapa); //display map

return 0;

}
```

Comment: By not able to display the map, does it output nothing? Does it output weird symbols? Does it run?

Comment: This is untested code but you probably want something like `cout << setw(10) << *(it->key)->first << setw(5) << *(it->key)->second << endl;`

Comment: when I tried the code out on an online compiler, it worked so it might not be the code... http://codepad.org/9mCzCxq8

Comment: i am using g++ compiler @datdo but still got the compilation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to output a `std::pair`, which is your key (i.e. the first template parameter of the map), but no stream operator has been defined for it. Use this:

```
std::cout << setw(10) << it->first.first
          << setw(5) << it->first.second
          << setw(5) << it->second
          << std::endl;
```

Comment: can you please elaborate "but it havent stream operator". @Denis Ermolin

Comment: @VitoCorleone havent = doesn't have

Comment: Yes, sorry for bad language.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
   cout << '(' << setw(10) << it->first.first << ", " << setw(10) << it->first.second << ") -> " << setw(5) << it->second << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Can please explain what was the mistake.@Remi

Comment: @VitoCorleone Items in the map are pairs; the `first` element is the key, and the `second` one is the value. In your case, the key is a pair itself, hence the syntax `first.first` and `first.second`.